# How to convert time in php to user friendly text?

Tags: php, string, date, time

I use the following code to display the time of blog posts on my website:

```
strftime('%B %e, %Y',strtotime($row->date))
```

Which returns the following string:

```
November 7, 2011
```

How can I adapt the above code to show (..st, ..nd, ..rd, ..th) at the end of the number. So I can show the date as:

```
 November 7th, 2011
```

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `date()` like this:

```
echo date('F jS, Y',strtotime($row->date));
```

Answer (score 4):

When using [`date()`](http://php.net/date), the `S` character is replaced with st, nd, rd or th:

```
date("F jS, Y", strtotime($row->date))
```